# Can I use the PHP session_id as name for a temporary directory?

Tags: php, session, character-set

I have a straightforward question for which I have not been able to find an answer anywhere. I would like to use `session_id()` as the name for a temporary directory (during file upload) which I then rename to something else when all files have been uploaded by the user. Is this possible?

What character set is used by `session_id()`? For instance, can it contain a comma which would be an illegal character for a directory name?

Comment: Since sessions are, by nature, transient it would not be aa good idea.

Comment: No need PHP does that all for you in that background [Please read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: thanks. I need to pass the temp name across 2-3 scripts though as I allow the user to delete individual files again etc. Can I simply do this in the $_SESSION variable then or better set a cookie? E.g.: $_SESSION['tmp_dir'] = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']. When a user uploads several files (one by one), will they all be stored in the same $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'] ? Thanks.

Comment: I just tried this and for every file upload PHP stores them in a different tmp directory. So that's no good. Well I still don'T know what character set the session_id uses but I guess I could just use a substr(str_shuffle($permitted_chars), 0, 32) where $permitted_chars are standard letters and numbers and then do a move_uploaded_file() to this temporary location.